# Using variable outside of for loop.

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

If I have this loop:

```
int i = 0;
int bestscore = moveArray[2][0];
for (; i < count; i++) {
    if (moveArray[2][i] > moveArray[2][0])
        bestscore = moveArray[2][i];
}

printf("\nComputer places %c at %c%c.\n", color, (moveArray[0][i]) + 'a', (moveArray[1][i]) + 'a');
```

I want to use the i value outside the loop, so this is what I did, but I believe there's a better way to do this by making a copy of the value or something like it?

Comment: If you want the last values of `i` this is ok (In this case it'll be `count`)

Comment: What  copy ? `i` will retain its value after loop also , its not local here .

Comment: What you mean better way to do it, you can probably initialize `i` in the loop to make it prettier, but this is ok!

Comment: the last value of i should be the 'bestscore' value anyways right?

Comment: @Jbox It will have value of `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you are asking, but to find the best score you could use:

```
int i = 1;
int bestscore = 0;
for (; i < count; i++) {
    if (moveArray[2][i] > moveArray[2][bestscore])
        bestscore = i;
}

printf("\nComputer places %c at %c%c.\n", color, (moveArray[0][bestscore]) + 'a', (moveArray[1][bestscore])
```